# pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, hyperledger-composer, loopback

I want to implement a passport-local strategy for composer-rest-server

```
COMPOSER_CARD=admin@stschain
COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=never
COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=true
COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=true
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
    "local": {
        "provider": "local", 
        "module": "passport-local", 
        "usernameField": "username", 
        "passwordField": "password", 
        "authPath": "/auth/local", 
        "callbackURL":"/auth/local/callback",
        "successRedirect": "/", 
        "failureRedirect": "/", 
        "setAccessToken": true, 
        "callbackHTTPMethod": "post" 
   },
}'
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
    "db": {
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "mongodb",
        "host": "mongo"
    }
}'
```

i ran this CMD : `docker run -d --name mongo --network 
composer_default -p 27017:27017 mongo` for started MongoDB docker container, and do all things needed for implement this strategy but when i run this cmd `docker logs rest` it show me `DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.`

How can I add this option `useNewUrlParser` known that I run mongodb in a docker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
    "db": {
        "useNewUrlParser": true
        "name": "db",
        "connector": "mongodb",
        "host": "mongo"
    }
}'
```

Comment: thanks @Siyu it's work like sharm, please you have information about the callback URL for this strategy ?